# Find difference of rising and declining values in dataset

Tags: python, pandas

This is something I've done before in Excel, but now trying it in python, and kinda stuck. Couldn't find libraries or native functions for that. I guess, **shift()** can help, but i don't know where can i use it

There is no need to keep all tickers in one df, it's just looks better imo

I made a pretty dataset of 10 tickers, here is a sample:

```
                       symbol             open
2020-05-03 00:28:00   BCH/BTC     0.0295400000
2020-05-03 00:35:00   BCH/BTC     0.0291680000
*******************
2020-05-03 18:05:00   BCH/BTC     0.0282650000
2020-05-03 00:28:00   BNB/BTC     0.0019586000
*******************
2020-05-03 17:58:00   XTZ/BTC     0.0003064000
2020-05-03 18:05:00   XTZ/BTC     0.0003065000

[1520 rows x 6 columns]
```

As you can see **time is an index and same for every ticker**

The task is make 2 more columns like this:

```
                       symbol             open       is_advancing           ratio
2020-05-03 00:28:00   BCH/BTC     0.0295400000                Nan             Nan
2020-05-03 00:35:00   BCH/BTC     0.0291680000                 -1    0.9874069059
*******************
2020-05-03 18:05:00   BCH/BTC     0.0282650000                  1    1.0028452501
2020-05-03 00:28:00   BNB/BTC     0.0019586000                Nan             Nan
*******************
2020-05-03 17:58:00   XTZ/BTC     0.0003064000                  0               1
2020-05-03 18:05:00   XTZ/BTC     0.0003065000                  1    1.0003263707

[1520 rows x 6 columns]
```

**is_advancing** shows if previous value was higher, smaller or same. **ratio** shows ratio between current and previous

I've tried to explain it as full as i could, but if have any other questions, feel free to ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were on the right track with shift. You can use np.select() to assign new values based on multiple conditions.

```
df = pd.read_clipboard(sep=r"[ ]{2,}")

print(df)
                       symbol             open
2020-05-03 00:28:00   BCH/BTC     0.0295400000
2020-05-03 00:35:00   BCH/BTC     0.0291680000

df['shift'] = df['open'].astype(float).shift(1)

conditions  = [ df['open'] > df['shift'], df['open'] == df['shift'], df['open'] < df['shift']]
choices     = [ 1, 0, -1]


df["is_advancing"] = np.select(conditions, choices, default=np.nan)


df['ratio'] = df['open']/df['shift']

print(df)
                     symbol open    shift   is_advancing    ratio
2020-05-03 00:28:00 BCH/BTC 0.029540    NaN      NaN        NaN
2020-05-03 00:35:00 BCH/BTC 0.029168    0.02954 -1.0    0.987407
```

If you want to do it on all tickers you could do something like this.

```
print(df)

                    symbol  open
2020-05-03 00:28:00 BCH/BTC 0.029540
2020-05-03 00:35:00 BCH/BTC 0.029168
2020-05-03 18:05:00 BCH/BTC 0.028265
2020-05-03 00:28:00 BNB/BTC 0.001959
2020-05-03 17:58:00 XTZ/BTC 0.000306
2020-05-03 18:05:00 XTZ/BTC 0.000307

symbols_list = df['symbol'].unique().tolist()
new_dfs_list = []

for s in symbols_list:

    df_slice = df[df['symbol'] == s].copy()

    df_slice['shift'] = df_slice['open'].astype(float).shift(1)

    conditions  = [ df_slice['open'] > df_slice['shift'], df_slice['open'] == df_slice['shift'], df_slice['open'] < df_slice['shift']]
    choices     = [ 1, 0, -1]

    df_slice["is_advancing"] = np.select(conditions, choices, default=np.nan)

    df_slice['ratio'] = df_slice['open']/df_slice['shift']

    new_dfs_list.append(df_slice)


concat_df = pd.concat(new_dfs_list)  

print(concat_df)

                    symbol  open       shift    is_advancing    ratio
2020-05-03 00:28:00 BCH/BTC 0.029540    NaN NaN NaN
2020-05-03 00:35:00 BCH/BTC 0.029168    0.029540    -1.0    0.987407
2020-05-03 18:05:00 BCH/BTC 0.028265    0.029168    -1.0    0.969041
2020-05-03 00:28:00 BNB/BTC 0.001959    NaN NaN NaN
2020-05-03 17:58:00 XTZ/BTC 0.000306    NaN NaN NaN
2020-05-03 18:05:00 XTZ/BTC 0.000307    0.000306    1.0 1.000326
```